# How can I look up the current/default guifont reliably?

Tags: gvim, font

I'm trying to configure my `guifont` and I'd like to see the current setting so I can e.g. keep the same font but change the size. Is there a way to check the current font that works reliably, even if no font has been selected in the current vim session?

A similar question was previously asked on mailing lists at http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/How-to-determine-current-font-in-use-td1181670.html but not sufficiently answered; `set guifont` only seems to get the current font if it's been explicitly set in the current vim session.

Comment: Relevant: `:h gui-font`

Comment: to keep font and change the size: https://github.com/habamax/.vim/blob/master/pack/habamax/start/vim-change-font-size/plugin/change-font-size.vim

Comment: And yes you have to have guifont specified in your `vimrc`.

Answer (score 5):

So it looks like if no `guifont` is specified in your vimrc, gVim will use some built in default font and it would not be reflected in `guifont` -- `set guifont` is empty.

But it turns out it is possible to change the size of your default font -- use `guifont` without name, just size:

```
set guifont=:h10
set guifont=:h16
...
whatever your default bitmap font supports
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in version 7.3.